# Android app and Actionbar with different themes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

In my Android application I need to have a black action bar and my content has a white background. The problem is that whenever I set the actionbar with a black background, all my dropdown spinners and textviews have a white background, and I can't see them together with my white content background. If I set the actionbar to white, the dropdown spinners and textviews have a black background and I can see them properly. I tryed customizing the style from the dropdown spinner with `android:dropDownSpinnerStyle` But i didn't succeed. How can I solve this?

Edit:
I just solved this issue regarding the Dropdown using the following:

```
<item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/customDropDownStyle</item>

<style name="customDropDownStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">

</style>
```

But I still have this issue regarding an EditText, in which I can't see it's background. I just can't find the attribute I should work with in order to solve the issue.

Comment: Move the answer from the question to an actual answer as mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was much easier to keep the style of the APP in a way that the dropbox/textfields would be visible, but changing only the style of the Actionbar like that:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>
```